# Why useEffect doesn't run on window.location.pathname changes?

Tags: reactjs

Why **useEffect** doesn't run on `window.location.pathname` changes? I get `loc` logged only once.

How can I make to run **useEffect** when pathname changes without any additional libraries?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const loc = window.location.pathname
    console.log({ loc })
  }, [window.location.pathname])
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Create a hook, something like:

```
const useReactPath = () => {
  const [path, setPath] = React.useState(window.location.pathname);
  const listenToPopstate = () => {
    const winPath = window.location.pathname;
    setPath(winPath);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("popstate", listenToPopstate);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", listenToPopstate);
    };
  }, []);
  return path;
};
```

Then in your component use it like this:

```
const path = useReactPath();
React.useEffect(() => {
  // do something when path changes ...
}, [path]);
```

Of course you'll have to do this in a top component.

Answer (score 25):

Weird no one mentioned this but, you can get location from `react-router-dom` using the `useLocation` hook. So you can just use that in the dependency array.
[Docs here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation)

```js
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(location);
}, [location.pathname]);
```

Edit:
This is a solution only for using react with web and you are using the `react-router-dom` library for web.

If you want to achieve this for cases where you don't have that library installed, and the other answers didn't work for you, you would need to do the following:-

1. Add a context<sup>{1}</sup> to the top level of your App.

```js
export const LocationContext = React.createContext<LocationContextObject>(
  null!
);
```

2. Set the value of this context provider with the location
3. When navigating, you need to update this context value with the new location, (create a custom navigation function and use it everywhere)

** Inspired from the source code of [remix-run/react-router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router) (react-router-dom)

{1} - You may want to search a bit more if you want to use a context at the top level since there are [pitfalls](https://blog.logrocket.com/pitfalls-of-overusing-react-context/) you need to keep in mind. You could also store it in a state management library of your choice.

Comment: This should be considered the best answered. Thank you bud!

Comment: @Sunamin34 - Yes this would work but the OP explicitly said **without any additional libraries**

Answer (score 5):

I adapted Rafael Mora's answer to work for the entire location object and also work in the front end of Next.js apps using the `useIsMounted` approach, and added typescript types.

`hooks/useWindowLocation.ts`

```
import useIsMounted from './useIsMounted'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'


const useWindowLocation = (): Location|void => {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted()
  const [location, setLocation] = useState<Location|void>(isMounted ? window.location : undefined)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted) return

    const setWindowLocation = () => {
      setLocation(window.location)
    }

    if (!location) {
      setWindowLocation()
    }

    window.addEventListener('popstate', setWindowLocation)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', setWindowLocation)
    }
  }, [isMounted, location])

  return location
}

export default useWindowLocation
```

`hooks/useIsMounted.ts`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const useIsMounted = (): boolean => {
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(() => true)
  }, [])

  return isMounted
}

export default useIsMounted
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. useEffect is only called when mounted so your useIsMounted() hook is redundant. You can remove it completely and achieve the exact same effect.

Comment: isMounted is used when setting the default value in useState `isMounted ? window.location : undefined`

Comment: When your hook executes, isMounted will always be false meaning you may as well set your default value to `undefined`. Then your useEffect executes when mounted so your  `if (!isMounted) return` is also redundant. The entire useIsMounted hook is redundant and should be removed.

Answer (score 4):

`useEffect` is evaluated every time your component renders. To subscribe to changes to `location.pathname`, you'll need to add a listener to the `window`'s `'popstate'` event that updates state, which tells the component tree to rerender.

[Rafel Mora's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443076/4722345) implements a hook using `setState`, which will cause  the component to rerender. You can then use the returned state value from the hook in your `useEffect` in place of `window.location.pathname`.

---

Related - here's the ESLint warning you'll see if you use `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`:

> Outer scope values like 'window.location.pathname' aren't valid
> dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render
> the component

---

If you're open to using a library, React Router offers a [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) hook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but for me adding listeners for `'popstate'` never worked and I was able to get `useEffect` to change when `window.location.pathname` changes, similar to what karolis did in their original question without issue. This is what I did:

```
  let path = window.location.pathname;
  /* potentially changes navbar on page change */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
      setScrollNav(false);
    } else {
      setScrollNav(true);
    }
  }, [path]);
```

This seemed to solve the problem I was having, but it seems I had a very different experience compared to everyone else so I would love to know your thoughts.

Comment: Similarly, the popstate event listener didn't work for me.  From my reading of the docs, popstate is only fired on the back button...so for me nothing was happening when the user was clicking links in my nav.

Comment: This will only fire one time which is on component mount. You could take out the dependency array, and it would be the same. 

In your case, there could be something that is causing the component to unMount and Mount which would make it seem like it is working.