# How to change background based on page url react js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I have a simple app with a few pages, now I would like to change the background color based on page URL
using react js,

What is expected?:

When a pathname is  `/movies` I want to change the background to red

Here is what I have so far

```
 import React from 'react'

function Testing() {
const[moviesUrlBackgroundColor, setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor] = useState('green');


const getMoviesUrl = window.location.pathname;


if(getMoviesUrl == '/movies'){
    setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('red');
}else{
    setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('green');
}

    return (
        <div>
            <Container style={{backgroundColor:moviesUrlBackgroundColor}}>
            
                Testing
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Testing

const Container = styled.div`
    background-color:green
`;
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following URL

```
app.js:38323 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

What do I need to do this working?

Answer (score 1):

You should have an extra check to make sure you have set background color or not.Your current code is causing rerender infinte times

```
 import React from 'react'

 function Testing() {
 const[moviesUrlBackgroundColor, setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor] = useState('green');
 const [bgFlag, setbgFlag] = useState(false);


 const getMoviesUrl = window.location.pathname;

 if(!bgFlag){
     setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor(getMoviesUrl == '/movies' ? 'red' : 'green')
     setbgFlag(true)
 }

return (
    <div>
        <Container style={{backgroundColor:moviesUrlBackgroundColor}}>
        
            Testing
        </Container>
    </div>
)
 }

 export default Testing

const Container = styled.div`
    background-color:green
`;
```

Comment: but now I need to refresh to see changes if users navigate to another page URL it's still the same until I refresh the page

Comment: Then you need to use a Higher order component in which you pass location and as soon as props change you change the background

Comment: Awesome! man this just made my work easier

Answer (score 1):

Use an `useEffect` block so you can perform side-effects effectively.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(getMoviesUrl === '/movies'){
      console.log("running")
        setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('red');
    }else{
        setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('green');
    }
  },[getMoviesUrl]);
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this works on if I refresh the page , I user navigate to another page url , the color it still the same ,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call `setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor` without wrapping in an `effect` which results in getting called recursively.

In order to fix this, you just simple set state as needed in this case is your pathname has been changed:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (getMoviesUrl == '/movies'){
    setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('red');
  } else{
      setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('green');
  }
}, [getMoviesUrl])
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this works on if I refresh the page , I user navigate to another page url , the color it still the same ,

Comment: What does the url look like that time?

Comment: eg `http://127.0.0.1:8001/templates` or http://127.0.0.1:8001/ `

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right as you said the color was still the same. Was it red or green? It's supposed to be green as the path is `movies` only :)

Comment: it just need to change the color based on that route if route is /movies/ theb color is red otherwise green, it works but on when u refresh the page

Comment: Do you mean you use `react-router` to navigate a different path without reloading the page?

Comment: I seem to know what's going on. It's because the value `window.location.pathname` won't notify as it changed to your component which means you have to ref this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442168/why-useeffect-doesnt-run-on-window-location-pathname-changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it, you're creating an infinite loop on your first if statement:

```
if (getMoviesUrl == '/movies') {
    // every time you change state, that causes your component
    // to re-render, and when it re-renders again you're checking
    // changing your state AGAIN, so it's an infinite loop
    setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor('red');
}
```

I'll would recommend using react-route for this and getting the url from params, and then update the background color on componentDidMount or useEffect hook when component mounts for the first time, to prevent infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

Window.location.pathname was resetting state each render, so it needs to be placed within the `useEffect` hook to prevent re-renders.

Also, this would be a good use-case to pass `props` to your styled component.
Also included this in the code below.

Here's a link to a codesandbox I made with the solution.
https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-mirzakhani-njmsh?file=/src/random.js:0-620

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  background: ${(props) => props.backgroundColor || "green"};
`;

const Testing = () => {
  const [moviesUrlBackgroundColor, setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor] = useState(
    "green"
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMoviesUrl = window.location.pathname;
    if (getMoviesUrl === "/movies") {
      setMoviesUrlBackgroundColor("yellow");
    }
  }, [moviesUrlBackgroundColor]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Container backgroundColor={moviesUrlBackgroundColor}>Test</Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testing;
```

Cheers!

Comment: unfortunately, this works on if I refresh the page, when user navigate to another page URL, the color is still the same?