# variable is false in console log, but react rendering as if it were true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a slider that has arrows to scroll through the items only if the items are too wide for the div.  It works, except when resizing the window to make it large enough, the arrows don't disappear.  The arrows should only appear if scroll arrows is true.

```
      {scrollArrows && (
        <div className="arrow arrow-left" onClick={goLeft}>
          &#60;
        </div>
      )}
```

But when I console.log it, even if the arrows are there, scroll arrows ALWAYS is false.  Here is the relevant code:

```
import "./ProjectRow.css";
import Project from "../Project/Project";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ProjectRow = (props) => {
  const rowRef = React.useRef();
  const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [scrollArrows, setScrollArrows] = useState(false);
  const [left, setLeft] = useState(0);
  const [rowWidth, setRowWidth] = useState(null);

  function debounce(fn, ms) {
    let timer;
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        timer = null;
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
      }, ms);
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setVariables = () => {
      console.log(scrollArrows);
      if (rowRef.current?.offsetWidth < rowRef.current?.scrollWidth) {
        setRowWidth(rowRef.current.offsetWidth);
        if (!scrollArrows) {
          console.log("scrollArrows true now");
          setScrollArrows(true);
        }
      } else if (scrollArrows) {
        setScrollArrows(false);
      }
    };

    if (!hasLoaded) setVariables();

    const debouncedHandleResize = debounce(setVariables, 300);

    window.addEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);

    setHasLoaded(true);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", debouncedHandleResize);
    };
  }, []);

  const goLeft = () => {
    const projectWidth = rowRef.current.childNodes[2].firstChild.offsetWidth;
    if (rowRef.current.childNodes[2].firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().x < 0)
      setLeft(left + projectWidth + 20);
  };
  const goRight = () => {
    const projectWidth = rowRef.current.childNodes[2].firstChild.offsetWidth;
    if (
      rowRef.current.childNodes[2].lastChild.getBoundingClientRect().x +
        projectWidth >
      rowWidth
    )
      return setLeft(left - (projectWidth + 20));
  };

  return (
    <div className="project-row" ref={rowRef}>
      <h3 className="project-row-title light-gray bg-dark-gray">
        {props.data.groupName}
      </h3>
      <hr className="gray-bar" />
      <div className="slider" style={{ left: `${left}px` }}>
        {props.data.projects.map((project, i) => (
          <Project data={project} key={i} />
        ))}
      </div>
      {scrollArrows && (
        <div className="arrow arrow-left" onClick={goLeft}>
          &#60;
        </div>
      )}
      {scrollArrows && (
        <div className="arrow arrow-right" onClick={goRight}>
          &#62;
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProjectRow;
```

The "scroll arrows true now" gets logged, but scrollArrows variable stays false, even after waiting to resize or just resizing between two widths that need it.

EDIT: Fixed it by removing the if on the else if.  I figured that might be the issue, but I don't know why it was preventing it from functioning properly, so it feels bad.

Comment: *"but scrollArrows variable stays false"* - How exactly are you determining that it is still false? In the code, you are doing the `console.log` before you set it. Also, if you `console.log` a state value right after you set it, it probably won't have the correct value, since React doesn't necessarily update the state right away.

Comment: I console.log scroll arrows at the top of the useEffect.  It must be true, but for some reason always logs false.  I also tried console logging in the else if, but it never ran - even if the arrows were showing before and after the resize.

Comment: Can you show your whole code, including the part where you define scrollArrows?

Comment: updated to add full file

Answer (score 0):

Your 'useEffect' doesn't look well structured. You have to structure it this way:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    // Functions
    window.addEventListener('resize', ...
    return ()=>{
        window.removeEventListener('resize', ...
    }
},[])
```

Please follow this answer and create a Hook: [Why useEffect doesn't run on window.location.pathname changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442168/why-useeffect-doesnt-run-on-window-location-pathname-changes/58443076#58443076)

Try changing that and it might update your value and work.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but it looks like the suggestion is just adding the return here.  I did, but it did not fix the problem.