# Context with data from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, use-effect

I'm trying to make a spotify stats app and I'm trying to make a context to save the token that the app gives you in the url when the user logs in.

**TokenContext.js:**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// token is the state
// logOut and logIn is a function for changing the state.
export const TokenContext = React.createContext({
    token: "",
    logOut: () => { },
    logIn: () => { }
});

function getInitialState() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    return token ? token : ""
}

const TokenContextProvider = (props) => {

    const [token, setToken] = useState(getInitialState);

    // Use Effect for getting the token form the url and saving it in the local storage
    useEffect(() => {
        const hash = window.location.hash
        let _token = window.localStorage.getItem("token")

        if (!_token && hash) {
            _token = hash.substring(1).split("&").find(elem => elem.startsWith("access_token")).split("=")[1]

            window.location.hash = ""
            window.localStorage.setItem("token", _token)
        }
        setToken(_token)


    }, [])

    const logIn = (token) => {
        setToken(token);
    };

    const logOut = () => {
        setToken("")
        window.localStorage.removeItem("token")
    }

    return (
        <TokenContext.Provider
            value={{ token: token, logOut: logOut, logIn: logIn }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </TokenContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default TokenContextProvider;
```

The problem is that the useEffect hook isn't working because it is not saving the token in the local storage and the url keeps the same when the user already logged in.

**Example of how the url stays:**
*http://localhost:3000/#access_token=BQA4OEmPw6VRknPFNW9Z2dS-uGZHbEJ3WbAWJy-jmsLFEy_PWMgMMfMYKqAQKdNgd6j1FDPIKYTNlztx2L1IgwC_gLvee-xx0hj8rKOVgDVtN1NktbhV4sHRtuzK_1EaRNGjrzxvkvXqdQ3jd0NiD4mHzd1uWC2udWTXejHDXHf9x8K3MxZGIQ&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600*

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` runs only once (when the context provider is mounted) - are you sure that the URL already contains the access token at that time?

Maybe you just need to add a dependency to your effect that will cause the effect to re-run when the URL changes as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58443076/7545496).

Comment: It is still not working, now I'm doubting if it is the useEffect hook or something else .